# How to change my notification tooltip theme?

Tags: themes, indicator

After installing LXDE to my Ubuntu 13.10 system, the notifications tooltip theme changed and it remains after uninstalling LXDE.

[image]

Also before that, pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd> in my laptop I could change the volume and brightness settings and a tooltip would show up indicating the current levels, but now that doesn't show anymore.

Comment: Can you try changing the theme in System Settings -> Appearance?

Comment: @Dash_plus_Java, yes I've done that but it doesn't work (the theme changes but no tooltip / wrong theme on tooltip). However, I have Ubuntu Tweak installed which also modifies the theme. I have tried changing the theme there but no luck

Comment: Try installing dconf-tools (`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`) and then running `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` in terminal.

Comment: For the second problem you should be able to use the [Keyboard Settings](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MDUaB.png)

Comment: @Dash_plus_Java, that only reseted my desktop settings (# of desktops, auto-hide sidebar etc) but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @wilf, the keyboard bindings for volume, brightness, etc. work. The problem is that the tooltip doesn't appear as before.

Comment: You could try using the [Compiz Config Settings Manager (CCSM)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/)

Comment: can you upload the content of the `/var/log/dpkg.log`?

Comment: @avinashraj please, do not use backticks!  [Formatting, backticks and editing](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7707)

Comment: @wilf, I have it installed but I can't seem to find the right setting. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: It us just it may have a setting for it - *due to my stupidity I mucked up external hard disk case, so can't access my main Ubuntu install at the moment, therefore cannot verify a few answers...*  From memory you can change the popup mini tool-tip  things and the right-click menu from ccsm, so I thought it may have a setting for this...

Answer (score 7):

Just remove xfce4-notifyd  package and reinstall notify-osd if is not installed. Restart your desktop session.

```
sudo apt-get remove xfce4-notifyd && sudo apt-get install notify-osd
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this software to change the notifications. It seems a little heavy handed, but reseting doesn't seem to be working for you.

[How to customize on screen notifications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128474/how-to-customize-on-screen-notifications)

Comment: Weird. This didn't work either. When I change the configutation and hit apply, it still shows the same tooltip (and no tooltip on volume controls)

Comment: Another thing that seems to fix this problem for others is purging the desktop that caused the issue. I'm not sure if it's possible, but try purging LXDE and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I always uninstall with purge. In fact I even reinstalled ubuntu-desktop

Comment: I would check out this post and see if you missed anything. It looks like removing the meta-package will leave behind a lot. [http://askubuntu.com/questions/86602/completely-remove-lxde-lubuntu-desktop-environment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86602/completely-remove-lxde-lubuntu-desktop-environment)

Comment: I got `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libm17n-0 : Depends: libgd3 (>= 2.1.0~alpha~) but it is not going to be installed
`

Comment: What command gave you that output @Barefeg?

Comment: The one from http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu for lubuntu

Comment: Well it seems like the only thing it is installing is unity-desktop. It just may be something old or another. Did it work to fix the notifications?

Comment: I installed (reinstalled) ubuntu-desktop in my previous attempt but it didn't fix anything.

Comment: Well I noticed `xfce4-notifyd` in the list of stuff to be purged, and that is what seems to be causing issues for others. If you can try `sudo apt-get purge xfce4-notifyd` and restart that may be the end of it.

Comment: Wow it finally worked. I don't know why it didn't purge it before.

Comment: It looks like the command from that website uses `apt-get remove`. That could be why ;)