# unable to remove the lubuntu desktop environment

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments

I'm using ubuntu 14.04.1. I installed lxde for lubuntu desktop environment. But it's creating a lot of problems for me, so I want to completely remove it now. I read the instructions online and followed them. I've removed all the files by all the ways explained on askubuntu and ubuntuforums. But it's not gone yet. But as explained in question [Completely Remove LXDE/Lubuntu Desktop Environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86602/completely-remove-lxde-lubuntu-desktop-environment) hasn't work for me. Please suggest, I don't want to re-install my ubuntu.

Comment: I think I've mentioned that it didn't work out for me. I've checked all the possible resources already before asking the question.

Comment: it is still the same question - you will most likely have to reinstall to remove *all* the traces done by installing other desktops - try a virtual machine to experiment with other desktops next.

Comment: Every time I try few new commands, I delete a few more files than the last time. And I've done this three times, but it's not gone completely.

Comment: exactly, it is extremely hard to reverse the changes, I have seen people totally break their desktops trying, your desktop will probably never be the same - there will probably be that one last font setting or color that wasn't set by installing a package - rather a script in a package that simply switched the variable - making it impossible to track and reverse all changes.

Comment: In the answer by "suhaib" in the link you gave above, there's a very long command. I'm afraid to use it, cause it seems to destroy a lot of things like chromium browser and much more. But I still tried to use it, but it's giving me errors that many of the lib-* files given in the command aren't installed and hence the entire command get cancelled before execution. Is there a possible way to execute it somehow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25665/discussion-between-mateo-and-lavee-singh).

Answer (score 0):

Run those commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge lxde
sudo apt-get autoremove lxde
sudo apt-get purge lubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove lubuntu-desktop
```

If the above doesn't solve your ptoblem totally then try this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove abiword abiword-common abiword-plugin-grammar abiword-plugin-mathview ace-of-penguins audacious audacious-plugins audacious-plugins-data blueman catfish chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg elementary-icon-theme fonts-lyx galculator gdebi gdebi-core gecko-mediaplayer giblib1 gnome-desktop-data gnome-icon-theme-full gnome-mplayer gnome-system-tools gnome-time-admin gnumeric gnumeric-common gnumeric-doc gpicview gtk2-engines-pixbuf guvcview hardinfo indicator-application-gtk2 leafpad libaacs0 libabiword-2.9 libass4 libaudclient2 libaudcore1 libavcodec53 libavformat53 libavutil51 libbinio1ldbl libbluray1 libbs2b0 libcddb2 libcolamd2.7.1 libcompfaceg1 libcue1 libdca0 libdirectfb-1.2-9 libenca0 libept1.4.12 libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers libfaad2 libfluidsynth1 libfm-data libfm-gtk-bin libfm-gtk-data libfm-gtk3 libfm3 libgdome2-0 libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libglade2-0 libgmlib0 libgmtk0 libgmtk0-data libgoffice-0.8-8 libgoffice-0.8-8-common libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgsm1 libgtkmathview0c2a libgtkspell0 libguess1 libid3tag0 libimlib2 libindicate-gtk3 libjpeg-progs libjpeg-turbo-progs liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0 libmenu-cache1 libmms0 libmodplug1 libmowgli2 libmp3lame0 libmpg123-0 libmusicbrainz3-6 libnet-dbus-perl libobrender27 libobt0 libonig2 liboobs-1-5 libopts25 libots0 libpisock9 libpostproc52 librarian0 libresid-builder0c2a libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsdl1.2debian libsidplay2 libswscale2 libtidy-0.99-0 libtie-ixhash-perl libts-0.0-0 libuniconf4.6 libva1 libvdpau1 libvpx1 libvte-common libvte9 libwebcam0 libwv-1.2-4 libwvstreams4.6-base libwvstreams4.6-extras libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util6 libxfconf-0-2 libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpath-perl libxvidcore4 lightdm-gtk-greeter link-grammar-dictionaries-en lm-sensors lp-solve lubuntu-artwork lubuntu-artwork-12-10 lubuntu-core lubuntu-default-settings lubuntu-desktop lubuntu-icon-theme lubuntu-lxpanel-icons lubuntu-software-center lxappearance lxappearance-obconf lxinput lxkeymap lxlauncher lxmenu-data lxpanel lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin lxrandr lxsession lxsession-data lxsession-edit lxshortcut lxtask lxterminal mplayer2 mtpaint ntp obconf openbox openbox-themes pcmanfm pidgin pidgin-data pidgin-libnotify pidgin-microblog plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-lubuntu-text python-pysqlite2 python-support python-xklavier rarian-compat scrot sylpheed sylpheed-doc sylpheed-i18n sylpheed-plugins synaptic system-tools-backends transmission tsconf uvcdynctrl uvcdynctrl-data wvdial xfburn xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4-notifyd xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-data xfconf xfonts-100dpi xpad xscreensaver xscreensaver-data && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop && sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -g unity-greeter
```

Comment: A few icons have changed, but desktop-environment is not completely removed, it's still there