# Removing DE in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, lxde

I installed LXDE in my Ubuntu 14.04. Now I am unable to remove it from login screen though I used PURGE and all same sort of commands. Now when I try to remove it terminal says

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                                          
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'lxde' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
```

And still i am getting option for LXDE at login

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Completely Remove LXDE/Lubuntu Desktop Environment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86602/completely-remove-lxde-lubuntu-desktop-environment)

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and change directory to `/usr/share/xsessions`. In there, use `sudo rm` to remove options you don't want to see in your login screen. Then log out and log back in again.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the LXDE option at login, run the following two commands in your terminal

```
cd /usr/share/xsessions
```

Then

```
sudo rm LXDE.desktop openbox.desktop
```