# Unable to uninstall lxde from ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, lxde

I want to uninstall lxde env from the ubuntu 14.04 but when I try to remove I get package not installed error.

```
apt-get autoremove lubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'lubuntu-desktop' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

apt-get purge lxde
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'lxde' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

The about screen shows **LXPanel 0.6.1**
I confirmed using below command also.

```
echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
Lubuntu
```

The lxde packages installed, I guess, are:

```
apt-get purge lubuntu-
lubuntu-artwork           lubuntu-artwork-14-04     lubuntu-core              lubuntu-default-settings  lubuntu-icon-theme        lubuntu-lxpanel-icons

apt-get purge lx
lxmenu-data                      lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin  lxsession-data                   lxterminal                       
lxpanel                          lxsession                        lxsession-logout
```

What's the problem here? Do I have to uninstall each one separately?  Help please.

Thanks

Comment: what is output of `apt-cache policy lxde`

Comment: @Ravan 
lxde:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.5.0-4ubuntu4
  Version table:
     0.5.0-4ubuntu4 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages

Comment: `apt-get autoremove` run this command

Comment: please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86602/completely-remove-lxde-lubuntu-desktop-environment)

Comment: You wrote: "The lxde packages installed, I guess ..." Why do you need to guess? Why don't you show us the correct commands? How did you install `lxde`? How do you get any response by issuing `apt-get purge lubuntu-` assuming you're a normal user and not admin? How and why are you running `apt-get` without `sudo`?

Comment: @DKBose I wrote that because I am a new to *inx envirmonment, so may be I am missing something. 
I don't remember the command used to install, I did this long back just to try. :)

Comment: @Ravan I use apt-get autoremove after uninstall of every software, so, that's not going to help. The marked solution is what I am doing. Also, I don't see anything in software center.

Comment: @DKBose I am running terminal as root.

Comment: have you tried [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86602/completely-remove-lxde-lubuntu-desktop-environment/102466#102466) in the above link

Comment: @Ravan the link says it is for 12.10, so, I am just afraid of doing it.

Comment: ok then don't try some one will help you!

Comment: You should not run as root if you're new to *nix.

Comment: @DKBose I understand that.  I need to start some application as root, that's why. I remain careful though. :)