# How to remove lxde from lubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, lxde

I am using lubuntu 16.10 on my laptop , and I want to remove the lubuntu desktop and replace it with it's xubuntu equivalents.

after installing the `xubuntu-desktop` package I tried to remove the lubuntu desktop by running the following commands

```
sudo apt-get purge lubuntu-desktop
```

and

```
sudo apt-get purge lxde
```

but both commands return

> package not installed, so not removed

so my question is **How do I remove the entire lubuntu desktop environment from lubuntu?**

Thank you.

Comment: Run apt update, try again and please edit your question to include the actual terminals output.

Comment: i've already run ´apt update´ and terminal output is ´package is not installed, so not removed´

Comment: To search for installed packages, try `apt search --installed "*lxde*"` and `apt search --installed "*lubuntu*"`

Comment: The short answer is you don't. Desktop Environments are multiple packages put together. It's relatively easy to install an additional one to any Ubuntu flavor but very hard to get rid of once installed. Uninstalling the meta-package only removes itself, not any of the packages installed with and by it. You'd have uninstall all of them and then you'd end up in a dependencies caos.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Completely Remove LXDE/Lubuntu Desktop Environment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86602/completely-remove-lxde-lubuntu-desktop-environment). The accepted answer is rather useless (see its comments for an explanation) but the top part of [Brian's answer](/a/708691/175814) should do what you want. The trick is to use Apt's "autoremove" command.

Comment: Just leave it as it is difficult to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Start in text-only mode**

Switch on your computer. Wait until the BIOS has finished loading, and press and hold Shift, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select the line which starts with Advanced options.

Select the line ending with (recovery mode)

Press Return and your machine will begin the boot process.

After a few moments, your PC should display a menu with a number of options, including Drop to root shell prompt. Press Return with this option highlighted.

The PC will start in a terminal.

**Run these commands:**

Mount partitions in read-write mode

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
```

Update repositories

```
apt-get update
```

Install aptitude and deborphan

```
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
```

Eliminate the components of lxde that are not necessary in xubuntu

```
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(lxde),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(xubuntu-desktop))))'
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(lubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(xubuntu-desktop))))'
```

**Reinstall xubuntu-desktop**

```
apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
```

**Eliminate orphan packages**

```
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
```

**Remove unnecessary packages**

```
apt-get autoremove
```

**Remove downloaded packages**

```
apt-get clean
```

**Restart system**

```
reboot
```